# processing.js, access via form button?

Tags: javascript, html, processing.js

I need to click a HTML button and change a value in processing.js. This seems like it would be simple, but something is wrong here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../../processing.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="application/processing">
int color =80;
void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
  stroke(255);
}
void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(color);
  ellipse(100, 100, 160, 160);
}

function changeColor(newColor){
    color = newColor;
}
</script>
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas></p>
<div style="height:0px;width:0px;overflow:hidden;"></div>

<button onClick="changeColor(150)">Change Color</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `int color = 80;` to `var color = 80;` and
`<script type="application/processing">` to `<script type="text/javascript">`
and you should be good.

This is a concept known by the terms `loose typing` and `dynamic typing` (which means that a JS variable can hold different data types at different times depending on context). So, you don't define any types here.

Comment: Thanks Saket, that makes sense. but I tried and It did not work. I think there is an additional problem.

Comment: Oh, I edited my response to make an additional change (the script tag). Please take note.

Comment: I'm not saying that is wrong regarding the script tag, ... I'm saying I'm not convinced it is right. The processingjs.org site has examples that follow the script tag format that I used. Fwiw,  Most of the script (several hundred lines) are written in Java with an occasion javascript line thrown in which worked fine (e.g., document.getElementById...).

Answer (score 0):

To get this working, change your sketch function to:

```
int myColor = 80;
void changeColor(newColor) {
  myColor = newColor;
}
```

change your button code to be the following:

```
<button onClick="Processing.instances[0].changeColor(150)">
  Change Color
</button>
```

The reason it didn't work before is that

1. The browser does not execute code in a `<script>` block unless it has `type="text/javascript'`. So unlike a normal JavaScript block, the changeColor function is not global to the page.
2. Since the function is not global, you need to refer to it through the Processing instance, with the `Processing.instances` array.
3. Your variable named `color` would stomp on the Processing API function called `color()` so I changed the name of your variable
4. I changed your JavaScript function to a Processing function; Processing.js attaches Processing functions to the sketch when parsing it, which means you can call it yourself later.